# How to setup connection to HIVE using PySpark and SparkSession (How do I add username and password)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to access tables in Hive using `PySpark` and after reading a few other posts, this is the way people recommend connecting to Hive. But it doesn't work. Then I realize I must probably pass my username and password, but I can't understand how to do it. So is there a way to pass the username and pw when setting up `SparkSession`, or what else could be the problem?

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":

# create Spark context with Spark configuration
spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("interfacing spark sql to hive metastore without configuration file")
      .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://my_server:10000")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
df = sc.parallelize([(1, 2, 3, 'a b c'),(4, 5, 6, 'd e f'),(7, 8, 9, 'g h i')]).toDF(['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4'])
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("test_spark")
```

Traceback

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1575789516697_258641 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1122)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1168)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:780)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark connects to Hive directly. No need to pass user name and password, just pass the `hive-site.xml` while submit the spark application.

Use this bellow code,

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

   sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("ApplicationName").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

While submitting your application pass the hive-site.xml file,
AS,

```
spark-submit --files /<location>/hive-site.xml --py-files <List_of_Pyfiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding below to config

```
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", your_warehouse_location)
```

Use [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html) as reference.